# Confused on how to use SESSIONS properly? For PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am rather confused on how the sessions work. I am using the GET functions and using Sessions, however it seems that I am stuck. My returned value does not change even if i click on a different department.

```
<?php
session_start();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_submission_result)) {
    $adopt_id = $row['a_id'];
    $promote_id = $row['p_id'];

    $adopt_dept = $row['a_department'];
    $promote_dept = $row['p_department'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $i++;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href ='ideaSubmission.php?a_id = $adopt_id' style='color:     black; text-decoration: none;'>" . $row['a_title'] . "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href ='viewDepartment.php?a_department = $adopt_dept' style='color: black; text-decoration: none;'>" . $row['a_department'] . "</a>";
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href ='ideaSubmission.php?p_id = $promote_id' style='color: black; text-decoration: none;'>" . $row['p_title'] . "</a>";
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href ='viewDepartment.php?p_department = $promote_dept' style='color: black; text-decoration: none;'>" . $row['p_department'] . "</a>";
    echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

$_SESSION['a_department'] = $_GET[$adopt_dept];
?>
```

I am clicking on the hyperlink that directs to **viewDepartment.php**, and the other page that it would direct to is:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['a_department'])) {
$adopt_dept = $_GET['a_department'];
} else {`enter code here`
echo"not working";
 }
?>
<?php echo "$adopt_dept"; ?>
```

Comment: google it .... its not a tutorial site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for session and not on get:

```
<?php
session_start();
$adopt_dept = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['a_department'])) {
   $adopt_dept = $_SESSION['a_department'];
 } else {
   echo"not working";
 }
?>
<?php echo $adopt_dept ?>
```

Comment: Possibly due to minor mistakes: (a) if the session var does not exist, the last line will raise a notice, (b) there's no indentation in the `if` and `else` clauses, (c) the quotes around the variable in the last line are not necessary. I've just fixed a syntax error too. Not major issues, but great if you can edit to fix them!